# How to make digiKam remember Google's Two-factor Authentication password?

Tags: kubuntu, google-picasa, digikam

I use digiKam on Kubuntu 12.10 to organise my photos and really like being able to upload to Picasaweb using kipiplugins.
Unfortunately after having set up Google two-factor authentication I now need to create an application specific password each time I want to upload from digiKam.

This behaviour is a bug which seems to have been fixed upstream according to https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292223 in digiKam 2.7.0.

I am using digiKam 2.8.0 on KDE Development Platform 4.9.5, with libkipi 1.6.0 (according to digiKam). Is there a reason why this bug-fix seems not to have been applied to my version of digiKam? I have been upgrading rather than reinstalling, so is there some config file or token file that needs to be deleted to allow the correct behaviour?

Alternatively is there a ppa version of digiKam with this functionality available?

Comment: You could look the password up in KWallet, where it is saved, (but not reread unfortunately). This is faster than getting a new password each time from Google. It does not solve the bug, but makes it less annoying.

Comment: Thanks @IngolfSchaefer, this is what I've started doing and it definitely improves the workflow somewhat.

Comment: Known bug, should be resolved in Digikam according to the KDE BugDB - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=292223

Answer (score 1):

If you go into your google account's security settings you can setup application specific passwords.

https://www.google.com/settings/security then click on "Authorising applications and sites"

Make one for digikam and then use this password where you would normally use your regular google password.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but I am creating an application specific password. However, digiKam does not save this password, and I need to create a new one each time I want to upload to Picasa.